# How to handle special characters like ampersand (&), present in attribute in JIBX binding

Tags: java, xml, binding, xml-parsing, jibx

Jibx gives error if XML contains special characters like &. I need to correctly bind text in attributes to corresponding java property. 
I cannot use style="cdata" as its an attribute not child tag.
my XML contains -

```
<Comments>
 <Comment Name="Res_Notes" Text="BED PREFERENCE: http://www.abcd.com?a=b&c=d"/>
</Comments>
```

How can I handle it?
The Text attribute contains URL (with get parameters seperated by ampersand) so I cannot replace `&` with `&amp;` otherwise the URL will become invalid.

Is there any way to handle this at JibX level??

Comment: That's simply not a valid XML element. It's not jibx-specific - it's plain invalid XML. Where did you get it from, and can you fix that source?

Comment: XML doesn't contain special characters like &. If it does, it's not XML. No XML-based tool will handle such input.

Answer (score 0):

Sameer,
This is invalid XML.
If you use JiBX, you shouldn't have to worry about this. If you set your JiBX object to a string, for example:

> name = "BED PREFERENCE: http://www.abcd.com?a=b&c=d";

JiBX will automatically convert this to valid XML when you marshal your object:

> <Comments>
>    <Comment Name="Res_Notes" Text="BED PREFERENCE: http://www.abcd.com?a=b&amp;c=d"/>
>   </Comments>

JiBX will also automatically convert the XML back to a regular java string when it unmarshals the XML.

I hope this helps.

Don Corley
JiBX contributor